# Cómo leer un arreglo de números?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, jade

javascript estoy haciendo un arreglo e intentar ordenarlo, pero no me está mostrando el mensaje.

```
form
        input#numero(type='number',required,min="0")
        input(type='submit', onclick='bubblesort()', value='Enviar')
    script.
        function bubblesort(){
          var a[] = document.getElementById('numero').value;
          var arr2 = [];
          var i;
          console.log(temp+)
            for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
              if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = temp;
              }
            }
            alert(a);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El input de tipo number te permite solo agregar un numero. Puedes tener un input de tipo text e ingresar los numeros separados por un espacio y luego convertirlo a un array con la funcion split(' ')

```
var value = document.getElementById('numero').value;
a = value.split(' ')
```

Ademas al ejecutar el onclick dentro de un form hace que se refresque el navegador, para evitar ese comportamiento tienes que escribir

```
  <input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault(); bubblesort()" value="Enviar"/>
```

En resumen quedaria asi

```
  <script>
    function bubblesort(){
      var value = document.getElementById('numero').value;
      a = value.split(' ')
      var swapped;
      do {
          swapped = false;
          for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
              if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                  var temp = a[i];
                  a[i] = a[i+1];
                  a[i+1] = temp;
                  swapped = true;
              }
          }
      } while (swapped);
      console.log(a)
    }
  </script>

  <form>
    <input id="numero" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault(); bubblesort()" value="Enviar"/>
  </form>
```

Ej online http://plnkr.co/edit/hqrF0FFk966dT4JMi5Fz?p=preview

Comment: no me lo ordena !

Comment: eso creo que seria una diferente pregunta de la original. Igual actualice el algoritmo para que ordenara

Answer (score 0):

Escribí tu código, y el problema es que en JavaScript no puedes convertir tu elemento con el id "numero" a un arreglo, y es donde se interrumpe su ejecución.
Tu función bubblesort() quedaría de la siguiente manera, sin embargo lo que tienes dentro de tu ciclo for no funcionaría al no ser la variable "a" un arreglo.

```
function bubblesort()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('numero').value;
    var arr2 = [];
    var i;
    //console.log(temp+);
    for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) 
    {
        if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
            var temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i+1];
            a[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
    alert(a);
}
```

Comment: como haría la variable a como un arreglo?

Comment: @ito2307gm No puedes como tal, a menos que ocupes una función split, pero no veo el caso al ser tu variable un número. Tendrías que añadir la variable a un arreglo, para que de tal forma pudiera ser ordenado con tu método burbuja. Lo que podrías hacer, es que a partir del número dado en la variable, pudieras determinar una serie de números a partir del que ya diste, por ejemplo a=4 entonces determinar que b[0]=4, b[1]=3, b[2]=2, etc. Realmente todo depende de lo que quieras hacer específicamente con tu programa.